# How to check if a horizontal slider is at the beginning or the end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a Javascript horizontal slider with next and previous arrows.

I'm getting the page width and then the ul list width (the content of the slider, they are like a number of steps). I calculate the total width (including the ul list and the arrows) and I set a margin left every time a user press the next arrow or the previous arrow so the list will be moved and see new options (with overflow hidden).

```
Slider_About = {
    aboutslider: function() {
        var page_width = $(window).width();    
        var arrows_width = 50;
        var ul_list_width = 1;
        $(".slider_wrapper ul.list li").each(function() {
            ul_list_width += parseInt($(this).width());
        });

        if (page_width >= ul_list_width) {
            return false;
        }

        //set the width of the ul list and give space to next and previous arrow
        var width_in_total = parseInt(page_width - arrows_width);

        // Add navigation
        $(".slider_wrapper").before('<p class="navig previous"></p>');
        $(".slider_wrapper").after('<p class="navig next"></p>');

        // Re-set new width to elements
        $(".slider_wrapper").css({
            width: width_in_total+"px",
            overflow: "hidden",
            float: "left"
        });

        $(".slider_wrapper ul.list").width(ul_list_width);

        $(".slider_wrapper .navig.previous").click(function() {
            slide("previous");
        });
        $(".slider_wrapper .navig.next").click(function() {
            slide("next");
        });

        slide = function(arrow_dir) {
            var width_slided = width_in_total;
            if (arrow_dir == "next") {
                var width_slided = (-1) * width_in_total
            }
            var margin_to_move = parseInt($(".slider_wrapper_block ul.list").css("marginLeft")) + parseInt(width_slided);
            alert("list width:"+ul_list_width+" , margin width:"+margin_to_move);

            /*if(new_margin == "0") {
                marginLeft: 0   
            }*/

            $(".slider_wrapper_block ul.list").animate({
                    marginLeft: margin_to_move
                },
                100,
                "swing",
                function() {
                    // callback
                }
            );
        };
    }
};
```

What I'm trying to figure out now is how to check when the slider is at the beginning or at the end? Let's say a slider with 6 steps is at the beginning:
Previous arrow - Step 1 - Step 2 - Step 3 - Next arrow

How can I prevent to click the previous arrow and move the list which means it will show an empty space as there's anything there?
When I click next the slider will show step4,5,6. Then again I want to prevent the user from clicking next again as there are no more steps.

I hope someone can help me with this, thank you

Comment: Firebug can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length` to get the number of item to display :

```
var numItem = $(".slider_wrapper ul.list li").length;
```

Initialize a variable as 1 (which is the number of the current step).

Each time you click next arrow, you incremment this variable. And finally check of this var (current step) is equal to the number of items (numItem) to display or not the next arrow.

Here is an exemple (Not tested) :

```
Slider_About = {
    aboutslider: function() {
        var page_width = $(window).width();    
        var arrows_width = 50;
        var ul_list_width = 1;
        var currentPage = 1;//Added
        var numItems = $(".slider_wrapper ul.list li").length;//Added
        $(".slider_wrapper ul.list li").each(function() {
            ul_list_width += parseInt($(this).width());
        });

        if (page_width >= ul_list_width) {
            return false;
        }

        //set the width of the ul list and give space to next and previous arrow
        var width_in_total = parseInt(page_width - arrows_width);

        // Add navigation
        $(".slider_wrapper").before('<p class="navig previous"></p>');
        $(".slider_wrapper").after('<p class="navig next"></p>');

        // Re-set new width to elements
        $(".slider_wrapper").css({
            width: width_in_total+"px",
            overflow: "hidden",
            float: "left"
        });

        $(".slider_wrapper ul.list").width(ul_list_width);

        $(".slider_wrapper .navig.previous").click(function() {
            slide("previous");
        });
        $(".slider_wrapper .navig.next").click(function() {
            slide("next");
        });

        slide = function(arrow_dir) {
            var width_slided = width_in_total;
            if (arrow_dir == "next") {
                currentPage++//Added
                var width_slided = (-1) * width_in_total;
                if(currentPage == numItems){//Added
                    $(".slider_wrapper .navig.next").fadeOut(200);//Added
                }else{//Added
                    $(".slider_wrapper .navig.next").fadeIn(200);//Added
                }//Added

            }else if (arrow_dir == "previous") {//Added
                currentPage--//Added
                if(currentPage == 1){//Added
                    $(".slider_wrapper .navig.previous").fadeOut(200);//Added
                }else{//Added
                    $(".slider_wrapper .navig.previous").fadeIn(200);//Added
                }//Added
            }//Added
            var margin_to_move = parseInt($(".slider_wrapper_block ul.list").css("marginLeft")) + parseInt(width_slided);
            alert("list width:"+ul_list_width+" , margin width:"+margin_to_move);

            /*if(new_margin == "0") {
                marginLeft: 0   
            }*/


            $(".slider_wrapper_block ul.list").animate({
                    marginLeft: margin_to_move
                },
                100,
                "swing",
                function() {
                    // callback
                }
            );
        };
    }
};
```